# Server-2008 tag synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I hope I'm not bypassing the synonym process - IMO the tag [server-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/server-2008) should be added as a synonym of [windows-server-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008), and/or the existing 4 questions should be retagged.

Thoughts, or will someone Be Bold and do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not wrong, looks like a few snuck in since we last did this dance. I'll deal with 'em with the mod-hammer.

Comment: Yay for mod hammer